# CORS - Content-Type and bodys

Tags: post, xmlhttprequest, content-type

I need some help understanding a bad api, for more context about the application I am working on read my 2 other questions that I asked before. I am working with an api that has a badly coded preflight check, and I don't have control over the server so I can't change how it works, but there has to be a way to solve this as I can use Thunder Client in VS code (its POSTMAN but worse) as well as reqbin.com, here is an exampe: https://reqbin.com/lmtz5jqj set the content to json and the body to: `{"signature":"te20b"}`

I have no idea why I can set the content type to applcation/json on these services and send the request but then I do it in my localhost with XMLHttpRequest it does not work!

Any help appiciated!

Edit: Chrome said the error was: CORS: preflightmissingalloworiginheader, if you want proof I can link a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

I worked on a project with a Frontend developer. Being the backend developer, I sent APIs to be consumed in the Frontend application. Before sending the APIs, I tested it with postman and Thunder Client and it worked as expected. However, the frontend developer contacted me saying that he's not able to consume the APIs. He had similar error as the one in your question. The issue was due to cors policy. I already whitelisted the Frontend local server domain and  the company's domain,  I was very sure the error wasn't from the Backend (Django) code.  To fix the error, I turned to the server (Nginx) and allowed in coming POST, PUT and DELETE REQUESTS.
API testing tools weren't blocked from running those requests, but the frontend App was blocked! You could do well to contact that Backend developer. You could also turn off cors policy from the browser you're using. That might fix that error for you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but this does not really answer my question, because I can't really contact the backend, this is a "public" api, but there is not really any docs and it's also setup really bad!

Comment: @Philip Magyar. Check out this extension on chrome https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf?hl=en   You can install it on your chrome browser and then use it to allow access to the APIs.

Comment: Hi, It did not really help in my situation but thanks for the tool! Any ideas why it would work for tools that are testing the api but not the aplication the same? Is the origin different or what?

Comment: Hi again! I was able to resolve my issue, for some reason I could not request this api with js code, but using the php code that reqbin generated (i was lazy), solved my issue :)